# What are the names of Shia hadeeth books?

Tags: hadith, shiism, uloom-al-hadith, books

Asalam-o-alekum,
I need the names of hadeeth books acceptable by Shia scholars. Also want to know if their Arabic version and Urdu/English translation is available on PDF.

Also I need book which has biography of raavis (narrators) of hadeeth in Shia books. If that book is also available in PDF with Urdu and English translation then that would be great.

Thanks
Lateef

Comment: I think this is already covered in [Has anybody ever complied a book of Shi'a authentic hadiths](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18173/has-anybody-ever-compiled-a-book-of-shia-authentic-hadiths) and in [How did the Shiite hadith sources originate, what are the authentic sources of hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13040/how-did-the-shiite-hadith-sources-originate-what-are-the-authentic-sources-of-h)

Comment: Related [Online database/Apis for Shia Hadiths](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/48986/11938)

Answer (score 2):

> What are the names of Shia hadeeth books?

In a nutshell:

As much as I know, there are four books which are considered as the most reliable ahadith (hadiths) books from the viewpoint of Shia Islam; they are as follows:

- Al-Kafi
- Tahdhib
- Al-Istibsar
- Man la yahdur

Source and more study: [The_Four_Books](http://en.wikishia.net/view/The_Four_Books)

Answer (score -1):

Wasail Al Shia is one of the most notable and comprehensive collection of shia jurisprudential hadith, rigorously covering every area of religious law. It is an encyclopedic super-collection sourced in turn from earlier reliable Shia canonical collections like Kutub-e-Araba (Four Books) and many other reputable primary sources of hadith. It comprises of approximately 36,000 hadith organized into 30 volumes. You can read more about this book here.

The hadiths were collected and compiled by Shaykh al-Hurr al-Amili (d. 1693), who wrote in the  introduction  of this book, that for a long time he had this idea in mind, to collect narrations about sharia and practical laws from reliable books:

"And indeed, I have often demanded of my mind and my pen, and I have stirred up (awakened) my resolutions and my ambitions, to compose a book sufficient in achieving my ambition, an all-inclusive comprehensive book that is adequate in ilm (knowledge) and amal (religious deeds), with hadiths of shar’iee (legal) issues, and texts of faru’iee (practical, subsidiary) rulings, narrated in the reliable, trusted books."

An online english translation is available at: https://wasail-al-shia.net

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66252)

Comment: Thanks @Qaaf. I updated the answer to address the question directly.

Answer (score -2):

There are four major books of Shia Hadith, consisting:

1. Al-Kafi
2. Man la Yahduruh al-Faqih
3. Tahdhib al-Ahkam
4. Al-Istibsar